# Using all of the array values all at once?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay so what I want is to use all of the array value and check if any of those make the statement true. Here is what I came up with:

```
testArray = [1532,1542,1151]
myArray = [2532,1897,1151,2654]
if testArray == any(myArray):
    ##Then checks what value made the statement true
```

I tried that but it doesn't work. So I hope you guys have any ideas on how to fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You have it iterate it like this `if any(item == 1151 for item in myArray):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case,

```
if 1151 in myArray:
```

is simplest.

For a more general case than simple equality, the `any` built-in function may help -- equivalent to the above, for example, would be:

```
if any(x == 1151 for x in myArray):
```

but you could do some different check, rather than just the `==` check, on the generic `x` as it steps through the list's items.

Comment: Is there any way to actually check what value made the statement true?

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper not in a fully clean way with `any`, it just returns True or False, but there are alternatives -- perhaps best explored in a separate Q depending on what exactly you want, e.g is `isitthere, where = <some expr>` what you're after?  (No use explaining here, explain in your next question!)

Comment: Okay will do that. :)

Comment: Oh by the way I have one last question for you here. Is it a different case if you use 2 arrays? E.G:

`if myArray in testArray:`

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper, yes, totally different -- on lists, `in` checks single items, not sub-arrays (strings &c are different).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the value, if any, that made the statement true with something like this:

```
testArray = [1532,1542,1151]
myArray = [2532,1897,1151,2654]

value = next((t for t in testArray if t in myArray), None)
if value is not None:
    print('found value {}'.format(value))  # --> found value 1151
```